# How to match the multiple values in a list of list with another list of list with the same amount of values then put into a df?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, mapping

I have two lists of lists both with the same amount of multiple values. I want to match these values and then put them into a dataframe.

Example of the two lists:

```
Reason_lst = [['Too cool', 'Too sad', 'Too scared'], ['Too scary'], ['Too Wonderful'], ....]

TestDate_lst = [['2022-03-24', '2022-03-24', '2022-03-24'],['2022-07-05'],['2016-08-26'], ...]
```

I have a third list with ID's that they will also be part of the dataframe

```
ID's = ['1234', '1235', '1236', '1237', .....]
```

Expected dataframe output:

```
IDs            Reason              TestDate
1234           Too Cool            2022-03-24
1234           Too Sad             2022-03-24
1234           Too Scared          2022-03-24
1235           Too Scary           2022-07-05
1236           Too Wonderful       2016-08-26
```

So the dataframe will repeat on the ID that is assiocaited with the Reason and Date. I tried using `.explode` on both columns but then the Reason will keep repeating while the date does not match the reason.

Thanks for any and all help

```
TestDate_lst = [['2022-03-24', '2022-03-24', '2022-03-24'],
 ['2022-07-05'],
 ['2016-08-26'],
 ['2016-05-06'],
 ['2020-09-29', '2020-04-14'],
 ['2016-07-25', '2021-12-29'],
 ['2020-01-03'],
 ['2022-07-13',
  '2022-07-13',
  '2022-07-13',
  '2022-07-13',
  '2022-07-13',
  '2022-07-13'],
 ['2019-07-23'], ....]

Reason_lst = [['Too cool', 'Too sad', 'Too scared'],
 ['Too scary'],
 ['Too mean'],
 ['Too sarcastic'],
 ['Too happy'],
 ['Too angry'],
 ['Too loud'],
 ['Too upset',
  'Too crazy',
  'Too insane',
  'Too free',
  'Too fake'],
 ['Too loud'], ....]
```

You can see on the 4th Reason there are two dates.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), along with the output you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), then [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(zip(IDs, Reason_lst, TestDate_lst),
                   columns=['ID', 'Reason', 'TestDate'])
        .explode(['Reason', 'TestDate'], ignore_index=True)
      )
```

Output:

```
     ID         Reason    TestDate
0  1234       Too cool  2022-03-24
1  1234        Too sad  2022-03-24
2  1234     Too scared  2022-03-24
3  1235      Too scary  2022-07-05
4  1236  Too Wonderful  2016-08-26
```

#### uneven sublist sizes

##### dropping invalid sublists

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(zip(IDs, Reason_lst, TestDate_lst),
                   columns=['ID', 'Reason', 'TestDate'])
        .loc[lambda d: d['Reason'].str.len().eq(d['TestDate'].str.len())]
        .explode(['Reason', 'TestDate'], ignore_index=True)
      )
```

Output:

```
     ID         Reason    TestDate
0  1234       Too cool  2022-03-24
1  1234        Too sad  2022-03-24
2  1234     Too scared  2022-03-24
3  1235      Too scary  2022-07-05
4  1236       Too mean  2016-08-26
5  1237  Too sarcastic  2016-05-06
6  1240       Too loud  2020-01-03
7  1242       Too loud  2019-07-23
```

##### only removing extra rows

```
df = (pd.DataFrame([[I, R[:min(len(R), len(D))], D[:min(len(R), len(D))]]
                     for I, R, D in zip(IDs, Reason_lst, TestDate_lst)],
                   columns=['ID', 'Reason', 'TestDate'])
        .explode(['Reason', 'TestDate'], ignore_index=True)
      )
```

Output:

```
      ID         Reason    TestDate
0   1234       Too cool  2022-03-24
1   1234        Too sad  2022-03-24
2   1234     Too scared  2022-03-24
3   1235      Too scary  2022-07-05
4   1236       Too mean  2016-08-26
5   1237  Too sarcastic  2016-05-06
6   1238      Too happy  2020-09-29
7   1239      Too angry  2016-07-25
8   1240       Too loud  2020-01-03
9   1241      Too upset  2022-07-13
10  1241      Too crazy  2022-07-13
11  1241     Too insane  2022-07-13
12  1241       Too free  2022-07-13
13  1241       Too fake  2022-07-13
14  1242       Too loud  2019-07-23
```

##### filling missing values with `None`

```
from itertools import zip_longest
df = (pd.DataFrame([[I, *zip(*zip_longest(R, D, fillvalue=None))]
                     for I, R, D in zip(IDs, Reason_lst, TestDate_lst)],
                   columns=['ID', 'Reason', 'TestDate'])
        .explode(['Reason', 'TestDate'], ignore_index=True)
      )
```

Output:

```
      ID         Reason    TestDate
0   1234       Too cool  2022-03-24
1   1234        Too sad  2022-03-24
2   1234     Too scared  2022-03-24
3   1235      Too scary  2022-07-05
4   1236       Too mean  2016-08-26
5   1237  Too sarcastic  2016-05-06
6   1238      Too happy  2020-09-29
7   1238           None  2020-04-14
8   1239      Too angry  2016-07-25
9   1239           None  2021-12-29
10  1240       Too loud  2020-01-03
11  1241      Too upset  2022-07-13
12  1241      Too crazy  2022-07-13
13  1241     Too insane  2022-07-13
14  1241       Too free  2022-07-13
15  1241       Too fake  2022-07-13
16  1241           None  2022-07-13
17  1242       Too loud  2019-07-23
```

Comment: Got a ValueError: columns must have matching element counts. All have the same length so not sure why this would occur.

Comment: @Astro_raf this is in the `explode`, and means that some lists have uneven lengths. Can you provide the real example?

Comment: the actual lists are both 656 values in length and all values have either one value or multiple values. I can share more but not sure if this will help.

Comment: I'm not talking about the lists but the **sublists**. Can you run: `[i for i, (a,b) in enumerate(zip(Reason_lst, TestDate_lst)) if len(a)!=len(b)]`? This should return an empty list if everything is fine, else it gives you the indices of the list where there is a mismatch.

Comment: I understand now what you meant. ya, unfortunately, there are 283 mismatch sublist between the two lists of lists.

Comment: do you know if there is anyway to get around this?

Comment: How would you want to handle those cases? Would it be fine to drop them? Alternatively, is the date always the same in a given sublist?

Comment: it would be fine to drop them, as long as the Reason has a date that matches that is fine. The date differs depending on when the reason was tested.

Comment: This is not so clear, can you provide the expected output assuming you have `['2022-03-24', '2022-03-24']` in the first sublist for the dates, and the same as before for the rest of the example

Comment: I updated the list in terms of the mismatch that is going on. For you question, some dates do repeat if that Reason was tested on the same day.

Comment: I provided alternatives, pick the one you like

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your help and your beautiful logic. happy Holidays